# Return a 3rd party pybind type

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, drake

My C++ library depends on a 3rd party C++ library with its own bindings.

I bind a `struct` that uses `def_readwrite` to expose its members. One of its members is a type from the 3rd party library.

Basically I have:

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
  ClassFromThirdParty member{};
}

py::class_<MyStruct>(m, "MyStruct")
    .def_readwrite("member", &MyStruct::member)
```

In Python I try:

```py
from my_bindings import MyStruct

obj = MyStruct()
print(obj.member)
```

but this raises `TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type!`.

It's worth also noting that if I do:

```py
import ThirdPartyLibrary
from my_bindings import MyStruct

obj = MyStruct()
print(obj.member)
```

no error is raised. But I don't like this solution as the Python user would have to import `ThirdPartyLibrary` even if they don't explicitly need it.

How do I write my binding such that the first Python snippet works?

PS: The third party binding in question can be found [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/6274f77de4f9df4c96a4314cfe5097967915dcc9/bindings/pydrake/math_py.cc#L56). In the absence of a general answer, I'd also be happy to hear answers related to that library in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same in pybind11 as it is in Python -- you need to import classes before you can rely on them.

Add `py::module::import("pydrake.math");` to your `PYBIND11_MODULE` before trying to define function bindings that operate on a `pydrake.math.RigidTransform` as a C++ argument type or C++ return value type.

Comment: Right so that's what I tried without success. I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of pybind but at a best guess I'd say that pydrake.math should be built within the project (I'm using cmake). Otherwise, how would pybind know what I'm referring to. Drake is used in the CMake project though. Should I be including something that would make "pydrake.math" visible during the build? Indeed, I was even considering it might be wiser to build all of pydrake and use my build instead of the pip install (so the added context here is that I also use the pydrake library on the Python side).

Comment: See [drake_cmake_installed](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples/tree/main/drake_cmake_installed) build system demonstration in the subdir `src/simple_bindings`.  That sounds like exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well strictly I'm just trying to use my extension without a TypeError. Are you confirming that I must follow that demonstration to make "pydrake.math" visible to pybind?

Comment: You said that `import ThirdPartyLibrary` in the end-user Python source code file fixed the error.  That should imply that `py::import` in the bindings code should have also fixed the error.  If you still can't get it working even after adding `py::import`, then please post a fully self-contained example and reproduction recipe in the original posting, so that we can see what's _actually_ going wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my issue is because my pip installed pydrake is a different version from the one I build for the C++ library. I spotted an undefined symbol further up the python runtime error trace.